# $helper->getSessionFromRedirect() always returns null

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, helper

so for some reason I have a problem where getsessionformredirect is always returning null the log always outputs "session = "
returning null, 
I have looked through a lot of threads and even tried fb login example files from other areas but nothing. also I do get logged in, if i clear my cache and login via my site and then go to FB I am logged into facebook so the login is successful.

here is the code

```html
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '****','****' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('myurl/login_form.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
error_log("session = $session \n", 3 , "C:/wamp/logs/php_error.log");
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
      $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
      $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
     $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
 /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
     $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
     $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
  echo( $_SESSION['FBID']);
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: login_form.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

and incase you need to see auto load

```html
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2014 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to
 * use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary
 * form for use in connection with the web services and APIs provided by
 * Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use
 * of this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and
 * Policies [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice
 * shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
 * DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */

/**
 * You only need this file if you are not using composer.
 * Why are you not using composer?
 * https://getcomposer.org/
 */

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
  throw new Exception('The Facebook SDK v4 requires PHP version 5.4 or higher.');
}

/**
 * Register the autoloader for the Facebook SDK classes.
 * Based off the official PSR-4 autoloader example found here:
 * https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md
 *
 * @param string $class The fully-qualified class name.
 * @return void
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
{
  
  $prefix = 'Facebook\\';


  $base_dir = defined('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR') ? FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR : __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/';


  $len = strlen($prefix);
  if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
 
    return;
  }


  $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

  $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

  // if the file exists, require it
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    require $file;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a mistake in the URL the page was returning too, everything works, now to figure out why the link does not work in IE.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '****','****' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('myurl/login_form.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
error_log("session = $session \n", 3 , "C:/wamp/logs/php_error.log");
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
      $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
      $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
     $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
 /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
     $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
     $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
  echo( $_SESSION['FBID']);
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/
  header("Location: login_form.php");
} else {
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Comment: Provide information/explanation instead of simply copying the code over.

Comment: I am not what other information I can provide, i am trying to get the FB id's so that I can add that to my database to affiliate the fb account with my database, there are no error message to report.